# How to use DBContext with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am new to MVC and I dont know if I am even asking the right question, but I am using EF and followed a tutorial that uses DBContext, I would like to populate some data from My EF to display in a View which allows for CRUD operations.

```
Model:

[Table("ProjectInformation")]
public class ProjectDetailsViewModels
{
    [Key]
    public int pkiProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string DesignerName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectType { get; set; }
    public string FluidType { get; set; }
    public string PipeMaterial { get; set; }
}


public class ProjectDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ProjectDetailsViewModels> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my controller and I have only added the Create Method.

```
Controller:

public class ProjectDetailController : Controller
{

    private ProjectDBContext db = new ProjectDBContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Projects.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Movies/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        ProjectDetailsViewModels ProjectModel = db.Projects.Find(id);
        if (ProjectModel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(ProjectModel);
    }

    // GET: Movies/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Movies/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "pkiProjectID,ProjectName,DesignerName,ProjectType,FluidType, PipeMaterial")] ProjectDetailsViewModels ProjectModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Projects.Add(ProjectModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(ProjectModel);
    }
}
```

Below is my View :

```
View :

@model IEnumerable<AirFlo_Size_Programme.Models.ProjectDetailsViewModels>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DesignerName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectType)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FluidType)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PipeMaterial)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DesignerName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FluidType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PipeMaterial)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.pkiProjectID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.pkiProjectID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.pkiProjectID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Below is the error im getting :

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.ProjectInformation'.
```

So due to another post I read, I added the Following to my Model:

Ive checked and each of these Tables have a Primary Key.

Let let me know where im going wrong/ what im doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Try just `public int Id` on `ProjectDetailsViewModels` or decorate `pkiProjectID` with [Key] attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried both and am still getting same error

Comment: You didn't include your ProjectInformation model, so we can't really tell.

Comment: You need to put  [Key] attributes  to Id fields in all your models.

Comment: @Erik Funkenbusch : I originally used ProjectDetailsViewModels in place of the ProjectInformation(Which is my table name in my DB) but I got this error : Invalid object name 'dbo.ProjectDetailsViewModels'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `[Key]` attribute for the primary key field. Then only Entity Framework understands it as primary key.

```
public class ProjectDetailsViewModels
{
    [Key]
    public int pkiProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }  
    public string DesignerName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectType { get; set; }
    public string FluidType { get; set; }
    public string PipeMaterial { get; set; }
}
```

Also I think you are defining other fields in a wrong way.

```
public string ProjectName { get; set; }
```

This doesn't make any sense

I think it should be

```
public ProjectName ProjectName { get; set; }
```

or

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```